# autocomplete with ngrams generates duplicates

Tags: solr, autocomplete, search-suggestion

I am writing an autocomplete feature in solr. Ideally autocomplete would

- display suggestions if target occurs in any of the words, but prefer exact match over KeywordTokenzierFactory ngram edge match, KeywordTokenzierFactory ngram edge match over StandardTokenizer (or UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory) ngram edge match
- serve the document along with the suggestion.
- show unique suggestions only

This is my attempt at autocompleting:

```
  <field name="category" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true"/>
  <field name="categoryAutocompleteExactEdge" type="autocomplete_exact_edge" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="categoryAutocompleteTermsEdge" type="autocomplete_terms_edge" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <copyField source="category" dest="categoryAutocompleteExactMatch"/>
  <copyField source="category" dest="categoryAutocompleteTermsEdge"/>

  <fieldType name="autocomplete_exact_edge" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="30" minGramSize="1"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>


<fieldType name="autocomplete_terms_edge" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="30" minGramSize="1"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

handler:

```
 <requestHandler name="/suggest_category" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="rows">5</str>
      <str name="fl">category</str>
      <str name="qf">category^30 categoryAutocompleteExactEdge^10 categoryAutocompleteTermsEdge</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

I think the above handles the order of suggestion in accordance with the first requirement. It also allows you to fetch the document data along with the suggestion by changing `fl`. The problem I have is the duplication of suggestion.

If there are many documents with category:"GASTROENTEROLOGIST", then it is possible that category: "GASTRO APPOINTMENT" is never served. If faceting is enabled and rows set to 0, then the `qf` ordering is lost.

I am looking for all in one solution, but it appears to me that serving unique suggestions and also displaying document data is mutually exclusive. For example, if I move the categories to a new core, then the suggestion duplication problem vanishes, because I can force uniqueness. But lookups to the new core can't display additional document info.

This is my first time creating an autocomplete functionality and I am not exactly sure how to tackle it. It would be really helpful if someone experienced could explain the best strategies for handling autocompletion. Is creating a new core for every field with autosuggestion the way to go?

Comment: could you try by adding RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory in your fields defina]ition? https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/filter-descriptions.html#remove-duplicates-token-filter

Comment: Thanks for stopping by @AbhijitBashetti hm, removing duplicates tokens in a stream just makes sure the indexed terms for the document field in question does not have duplicates. I could still leave me with thousands of documents with a category GASTROENTEROLOGIST before GASTRO APPOINTMENT showed up in suggestion.

Comment: Creating a new core for every field does not seem like an ideal solution. Could you add an example of what you get with your query and what you expect instead?

Comment: @Seasers. I also didn't like the idea of maintaining a separate core with unique values just for autocompletion. After many tests I found that build in BlendedInfixLookupFactory does the job the way I wanted. I don't have the scheme with ngrams anymore, but basically you get a hit for every document that matches category. Such search is useful if you search on Product Name - because you wont have 100k products with the exact same name, maybe just a few. On the other hand ngrams are useless for searching on category, because you do have 100k of docs beloning to same category.